# How is a web service different from an MVC controller that returns JSON?

Tags: model-view-controller, soa

I am trying to understand "web services" and "service-oriented architectures". From what I can see, basically a client calls a web server (with GET or POST I presume) and is returned a bunch of XML. How does this differ from a client requesting a URL that is serviced by a web server using MVC. As in, the controller takes the GET/POST parameters and returns JSON (for example) to the client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most obvious difference is that the access of a web service is done with SOAP and not HTTP as on the Servlet (so no GET or POST for the service).

Also, it is a much more structred way of exposing a service to your clients, since there is the WSDL document where you actually inform the public of what your service can accept (as parameters). On a servlet there is no formal way to do that, and the servlet can accept any kind and noumber of parameters (on a GET request).